# In Storybook, how can I get the component decorator to override the global decorator (or not use the global decorator) for a specific story?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Based on the [documentation on decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators#decorator-inheritance), I would expect a component decorator to override a global decorator. It could be that I'm misunderstanding the functionality around the decorators and perhaps it is set up to add on to the decorator above it, but for my use case I need the global decorator to not be used for a specific story for a component. How can I achieve that?

You can see a demo of the problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6xn5b1

**.storybook/preview.js**

```js
/** @type { import('@storybook/react').Preview } */
const preview = {
  decorators: [
    (Story, options) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            padding: '100px',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          }}
        >
          <Story />
        </div>
      );
    },
  ],
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;
```

**Page.stories.js**

```js
import { within, userEvent } from '@storybook/testing-library';
import { Page } from './Page';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Page',
  component: Page,
  decorators: [
    (Story, options) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            padding: '50px',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          }}
        >
          <Story />
        </div>
      );
    },
  ],
  parameters: {
    // More on how to position stories at: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-layout
    layout: 'fullscreen',
  },
};

export const LoggedOut = {
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <div
        style={{
          padding: '25px',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }}
      >
        <Story />
      </div>
    ),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Curious to know how you solved this, if you have already.

Comment: I defined a parameter in the story and then looked for that parameter in the global decorator and if it was there I would not use the global decorator.